# Loading remote Angular MFE into React shell using Webpack's Module federation

Tags: webpack-module-federation

Can some one help me with an example to load remote Angular micro frontend application into React Shell using webpack's Module federation concept?

I have checked https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/ where React is loaded in angular. But I am looking for other way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

With webpack, you can put the bootstrapping of angular app in a mount method and export this method. This must be done in another file to avoid conflicts for angular to run independently.

*(Make sure to have the bootstrap.js file imported in main.ts, as used by  module federation)*

*remote/src/load.ts*

```
    const mount = ()=>{
              platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
                  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
        export{mount}
```

expose this new file with webpack from angular

*remote/webpack.config.ts*

```
output: {
   scriptType: 'text/javascript',
},

plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "remoteMfe",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './webcomponent':'./src/loadApp.ts',
        },   
})
```

load the exposed module in react app using webpack

*host/webpack.config.js*

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin(
      {
        name: 'host',
        filename:
          'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          RemoteMFE:
            'remoteMfe@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
        },
      }
    ),
```

import the mount method that was exposed from angular remote and get the root element(i.e. ) from angular mfe. This can be used as a regular DOM element

host/src/Example.js

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    mount();  
  }, []);   
  return <div className="left-sidebar-module"><app-root></app-root></div>;
};
```